# Requirements/Test Management tool with parallel hierarchies

Tags: gratis, project-management, software-testing

I am looking for a free software or SaaS for Requirements Management/Test Management with ability to link requirements/tests to two or more hierarchies, e.g.

```
Hierarchy 1 (UI prospect)
- Main Menu
  + Submenu 1
  | + Feature 1
  | + Feature 2
  |    ...
  + Submenu 2
    + Feature 123
      ...

Hierarchy 2 (User Story prospect)
+ Order Submission
|  + User Validation
|    + Feature 3
+ Order Processing
  + Account Processing
    + Feature 1
```

It should run on Windows or Linux, or be a web-application. Ability to maintaing several parallel hierarchies is my main concern, other features are not much important for me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think doorstop https://github.com/doorstop-dev/doorstop and mustard https://gitlab.com/trustable/mustard fit the bill